# Cooking meat and potato dish at same time & temp, I want to cook stuffed chicken breasts that require 375 degrees for 55 minutes

Tags: temperature

I need to cook two stuffed chicken breasts at 375 degrees for 55-60 min. and a hash brown potato casserole at 350 degrees for 40 minutes.  Help me calculate the correct temp. and time if I bake them together.

Answer (score 1):

Your hash brown potato casserole should be just fine at 375F (191C). Just cover it with foil if it starts to brown too much, and figure it may be done perhaps 5 minutes sooner than specified in the recipe.